# Magento 2.3.5 - Currency Dropdown Not showing in default Luma Theme

Tags: currency, luma-theme, magento2.3.5

I have installed Magento 2.3.5 version. I have set all required settings for multi store currency.

We have one main website and 4 store views.

**Store View and Currency Setup**

Main Website

- Main Store

  - Store View 1 - UK - Pound
  - Store View 2 - French - Euro
  - Store View 3 - Italy - Euro
  - Store View 4 - German - Euro
- we have set Base currency as Euro and Store view display currency based on language.
- Default display currency is Pound because UK is the default store view.

**Currency Rates and Currency Symbol**

- Currency Symbol automatically added after setting currency setup
- Currency Rates are imported manually.

**Expected Result:**

Currency dropdown and language dropdown at store front end header

**Actual Result:**

Language Dropdwon only shown. If i print Currency Count in Block file i get zero results.

**Block file:** Vendor\module-directory\Block\Currency.php

**Function:** getCurrencyCount()

Please anyone check this and let me know if anything i have missed or if this magento version have this problem.

Comment: Currencies do not need to be setup as stores you can setup currencies in the store configuration. go to Store > Configuration > General > Currency Setup. once you have setup the currencies make sure all the rates are correct in Store > Currency Rates

Comment: Yeah. I have currencies for store view and currency rates. But Dropdown not showing.
Please let me know if magento  2.3.5 have this problem by default or not. So only i can check with other themes. I have referred some demo sites. In all versions except magento 2.3.5 currency dropdown showing in luma theme. *Link to check all magento versions demo:* https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-demo-free-with-sample-data/

Comment: If the currency modal is not displaying it is most likely that you theme is possibly removing it or you haven't set the rates on the currencies